# Do you multiply or add when simplifying $λ$-expressions?

Tags: calculus, lambda-calculus

The question is to simplify this λ-expression
$(\lambda x. x) (\lambda x. \lambda y. y x) 8 (\lambda x. x + 1)$

My current thinking is as follows:

$(\lambda x. x) (\lambda x. \lambda y. y x) 8 (\lambda x. x + 1)$ = $(\lambda x. \lambda y. y x) 8 (\lambda x. x + 1)$

$(\lambda x. \lambda y. y x) 8 (\lambda x. x + 1)$ = $(\lambda y. y 8)(\lambda x. x + 1)$

$(\lambda y. y 8)(\lambda x. x + 1)$ = $(\lambda x. x + 1)(8)$

$(\lambda x. x + 1)(8)$ = $8+1$ = $9$

However, I am told the answer is 72. why would the 9 multiply the previous 8 after it's substituted in?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I agree with you here, but also wonder if you might have copied the expression incorrectly. Do you have an image (photo/screenshot)?

Comment: @md2perpe I am certain the inital expression is correct, as thats the question on the assignment. I do not have the mark scheme and am trying to solve it myself, it just others say the answer is 72. The answer may well be 9 and if you believe its 9 as well, it may well be that